# Return an error for duplicate entry Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

Supposing I have a table in postgres which has primary key created in c#. Im trying to insert a key which is a duplicate and will try to return an error if such an event happened. Im deliberately inserting a duplicate entry to simulate an error. The case being that If I have a insert command which has not been committed yet using NPGSL TRANSACTION then for some reason the code pauses right before the COMMIT section and another user creates a PRIMARY KEY, which generates the same key since the first transaction is not committed yet and inserts smoothly. The first transaction when executing the COMMIT will raise an exception. This is what I have in mind but its not working.

```
 command = new NpgsqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            return true;
        else
           throw new Exception("Data not inserted. Create new Transaction");
```

This code stops right in running executenonquery.

Comment: If you have a duplicate key value, `ExecuteNonQuery` itself will throw. You don't need to check the return value to throw another exception. What are you trying to do and where is the rest of the code? If you don't get exceptions it's because there's something wrong with the query or the rest of the code

Comment: Nope. It doesn't throw any error. My application just freezes.

Comment: that doesn't explain anything. Freezes where? `ExecuteNonQuery`? That means there was no insertion - the query was *blocked* waiting for the other transaction to complete. When the other transaction completes this one will continue. If the Command execution timeout expires, you'll get an exception

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? Why the multiple transactions? Individual commands like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE are atomic anyway, they don't *need* extra transactions. You *shouldn't* have long-running transactions anyway

Comment: yes. It freezes when executing ExecuteNonQuery. surrounding it with try catch has the same results. The reason is that im doing multiples inserts in one transaction and its should all or nothing. But the thing is all my primary keys are generated in c#. not auto increment.

Comment: It freezes because it was *blocked* and there's nothing you can do about it except perhaps lower the timeout. There's no exception, there's nothing wrong. It's waiting for access to a table locked by another transaction. Whatever you are trying to test, this is the wrong way to do it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Okay. lets make it simpler. Supposing I already have the 2018-01 as primary key in the table. Now, I want to deliberately add another row with the same primary key and raise an exception when executing ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: You aren't making it simpler. You misunderstand what your code does. It does *not* try to insert duplicates. It *waits* for another transaction to finish before it even starts inserting those duplicates. You are asking about breaks and ABS behaviour when the car isn't even moving

Comment: what I mean simpler is making the scenario simpler. and the scenario is the comment I just posted awhile ago.

Comment: And yet you insist on the same unrelated exampl. If you want to try to insert anything, make sure the *other* transaction is already committed. If you are inserting duplicates into a PRIMARY KEY you'll *always* get errors. What you see here has nothing at all to do with that

Comment: okay. you are the one misunderstanding it. You see, I know that it will freeze because it is a duplicate primary key thats why I said deliberately inserting duplicate key. Now, What Im asking is to raise an exception so that the application will not freeze in case it tries to insert duplicate primary key.

Comment: and its already committed BTW. Thats why I said that I already have the 2018-01 key in the table. Which means that It is already committed.\

Comment: instead of assuming, check [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) and run the query that shows the blocked and blocking processes.